# Formastic ,ActiveAdmin adding javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to add javascript action with formastic and activeadmin:

I have such form:

```
f.input :role, :as => :select, :collection => User.display_roles.each_with_index.map{|x,i|  [x,User.roles[i]]} , :include_blank => nil

f.input :organization, :input_html => { :disabled => false }
```

I would like to add javascript in which after change a role, organization will change. How to do it??

Answer (score 2):

I had to create a form partial.

At the end of the partial put:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(function(){
        $('#your_model_role').change(function() {
            what you want to happen goes here
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Following the idea of not having obtrusive js you can also put this into a js file (example: `utils.js`):

```
$(function(){
    $('#your_model_role').change(function() {
        what you want to happen goes here
    });
});
```

And then in `/config/initializers/active_admin.rb` put a line `config.register_javascript 'utils.js'`